# Is it possible to use JavaScript to track a http status of a URL at any domain?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

For example, I want to check whether some service of Google is working correctly from my site, can I have something like this:

```
// This is on my site
getWebsiteStatus('http://www.google.com/someservice', function(status){
  alert(status); // can be the status code like "200" or "404" or "500"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you'll find these issues:

- Cross domain limitations imposed by the browser
- Sometimes the reporting of errors from XmlHTTPRequest is buggy

The cross domain limitation can be resolved by using some proxy like http://www.corsproxy.com/ or http://cors.io. For example `http://cors.io/www.google.com/`, but I'm not sure what will be the proxy response in case of error or timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into AJAX: http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/

You see that the status code 200 is requested. You could check it on all the values you wish.

Comment: I think AJAX can't cross domain

Comment: It can in chrome extensions if you ask permission in the manifest.